# RadComboBox items becomes Transparent

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am having an amusing issue with one of my RadComboBoxes. It is connected to a skin that it utilized all through my web site. On everything except one page the RadComboBox looks and capacities effectively. However on one page, the background behind the select-able items becomes transparent.

This is what the definition looks like.

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadComboBoxProduct" runat="server" Height="200" Width="415" 
                                    DropDownWidth="315" EmptyMessage="--Select--" HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
                                    EnableLoadOnDemand="true" Filter="StartsWith" OnItemsRequested="RadComboBoxProduct_ItemsRequested" ForeColor="Black"
                                    Label="Product:">

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div style="float: left; elevation: above; azimuth: rightwards; height: 12px; width: 20px; background-color: black">

                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"Attributes['CUSTOMER_SHORT_NAME_MARKETING']")%>

                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: What telerik skin are you using for this combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the skins troubleshooting article which could prove helpful - https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/skins-troubleshooting#incorrect-or-distorted-appearance

Some pro tips:
- make sure that it is not IE compatibility problem as well as the problem is not caused by global CSS styles
- start to remove the page contents one by one until you find what is causing the issue